# Measure distance from an iPhone to an Object using proximity sensor

Tags: iphone, proximity

I have read many Forums on this topic but I still haven't found an exact answer. Is the iPhone's proximity sensor only a trigger that turns the display on or off or can one get a distance from the sensor to an object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proximity sensor won't be precise enough to give you distances, it's basically a light sensor...

Comment: Aren't the proximity and light sensors different things? I think,the proximity sensor is an IR sensor

Comment: you're right, otherwise it will cause bugs in the night... Anyway you can't do much besides knowing it the earspeakers are blocked by something or not (using UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification)