# Find distance from proximity sensor on iPhone in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, proximity

I know I can get the proximity state from UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification, but what I'm really after is a distance measurement. Does anyone know of a way to do that, preferably without accessing private methods?

This questions is similar - [Measure distance from an iPhone to an Object using proximity sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444078/measure-distance-from-an-iphone-to-an-object-using-proximity-sensor) but is nearly 5 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that as far as I know it's not possible. It's only possible to know if there's something near or not (bool - true or false).

Thanks it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion after digging deep. You can possibly reach it from a private method, but then what's the point. Thanks for replying!